# Why can't i use this string as a method call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script, for some reason when i use `contactForm.container[contactForm.container.config.effect]();` it says "contactForm.container.config is undefined " ... I can very well see it defined! what am i doing wrong? Thank you

```
<script>

(function(){

  $('html').addClass('js');


 var contactForm ={

     container: $('#contact'),

     config: {
          effect:'slideToggle'
            }, 

     init: function(){
        $('<button></button>',{
           text: 'Contactame'
        })
               .insertAfter('article:first')
               .on('click', this.show);

            }, 

     show: function(){
                contactForm.close.call(contactForm.container);
                contactForm.container[contactForm.container.config.effect]();
            }, 

     close: function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                  $('<span class=close>X</span>')           
                       .prependTo(this)
                       .on('click',function(){

                                  $this.hide();

                                             })
                     } 

  };
       contactForm.init();
    })();

</script>
```

Comment: There is no `contactForm.container.config` here. Just `contactForm.config`.

Comment: You meant, `contactForm.config.effect`

Comment: `contactForm.container` is a jQuery object which doesn't have `config` property.

Comment: `I can very well see it defined`...might need glasses

Comment: Don't you first need to instantiate the contactForm in the DOM?..otherwise it's still just a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config` is not a child of `container`. They're siblings.

You seem to want:

```
contactForm.config.effect
```

Comment: Thank you all for responding! I really appreciate it, it was so obvious yet i missed it, too early to choose an answer, i ll do it in a few

Answer (score 1):

It should be `contactForm.config` not `contactForm.container.config`. Change the call to:

```
contactForm.container[contactForm.config.effect]();
```